# failed to set environment variable - what happened?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, macintosh, macos

I tried to set an environment variable and made an error in the input due to a new keyboard I'm not used to.

In the input (and output) below, did I accidentally start a job of some kind?

I'm mystified by what happened.

This is bash on latest OS X.

```bsh
mbp:e4 m$ DATABASE_URI=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/e4-data?user=m&password=?"
> "
[1] 59932
[1]+  Done                    DATABASE_URI=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/e4-data?user=m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unquoted `&` started a background process which set an shell variable **just for that background process**. Having set the variable the shell exited. You then went on to set a second variable called `password`  with the value of question-mark newline.

Answer (score 2):

You have `&` in the URL and this sign mean put this command in background. You should set variable on this way (with single quotation marks):

```
DATABASE_URI='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/e4-data?user=m&password=?'
```